# LINQ2SQL doesn't return row if checking with null

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have following LINQ2SQL Query:

```
var map =
                dbContext.TCPDriverMappings.FirstOrDefault(
                      c => c.DriverFacilityId == tcpDms.FacilityId &&
                                 c.DriverControlledParameterId == controlledParamId &&
                                 c.DriverValue == value);
```

All the types are string.

In my DB i have a row, which must be returned by query.

When `value="0", controlledParamId =null and FacilityId ="abc"` this query returns null, but when i wrote following:

```
var test = dbContext.TCPDriverMappings.FirstOrDefault(
                          c => c.DriverFacilityId == "abc" &&
                                     c.DriverControlledParameterId == null &&
                                     c.DriverValue == "0");
```

test was not `null`

What am i doing wrong?

P.S. I also tried `c.DriverControlledParameterId.Equals(controlledParamId)` but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Check the SQL query getting generated through your LINQ query.

Comment: The NULL value in LinqToSql requires special handling. See http://blog.linqexchange.com/index.php/how-to-use-is-null-with-linq-to-sql/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that LINQ2SQL has a special handling for the expression `c.DriverControlledParameterId == null`. It is translated to the SQL `DriverControlledParameterId IS NULL`.
But `c.DriverControlledParameterId = controlledParamId` is translated to the SQL `DriverControlledParameterId = :p1`, even when `controlledParamId` is `null`. And in SQL `DriverControlledParameterId = NULL` is undefined and as such never `TRUE`.

**How to fix**: Handle the `null` case specifically:

```
TCPDriverMapping test;
if(controlledParamId == null)
    test = dbContext.TCPDriverMappings.FirstOrDefault(
               c => c.DriverFacilityId == "abc" &&
                    c.DriverControlledParameterId == null &&
                    c.DriverValue == "0");
else 
    test = dbContext.TCPDriverMappings.FirstOrDefault(
               c => c.DriverFacilityId == "abc" &&
                    c.DriverControlledParameterId == controlledParamId &&
                    c.DriverValue == "0");
```

Or like this:

```
var test = dbContext.TCPDriverMappings.FirstOrDefault(
               c => c.DriverFacilityId == "abc" &&
                    ((controlledParamId == null &&
                      c.DriverControlledParameterId == null) || 
                     c.DriverControlledParameterId == controlledParamId) &&
                    c.DriverValue == "0");
```

Or like this:

```
IQueryable<TCPDriverMapping> query =
    dbContext.TCPDriverMappings.Where(c => c.DriverFacilityId == "abc" &&
                                           c.DriverValue == "0");
if(controlledParamId == null)
    query = query.Where(c => c.DriverControlledParameterId == null);
else
    query = query.Where(c => c.DriverControlledParameterId == controlledParamId);

var test = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

That third option is what I would use. In my opinion, this is the more readable than option 2 and has no repeated code like the first one.

Comment: Daniel, thanks a lot, i got the idea and your code works great!

Comment: @АлексейВоскресенский: You are welcome. Please check the updated answer for more options on how to write it.